# Spring, redirect/forward vs returning the page

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

I do understand a difference between redirect and forward, but can't understand why should we use them? Isn't it simpler just to return a String ( page in view ).

For example, there are two controller methods. One of them returns a page, another redirects. Why can't we return page in both examples?

```
@GetMapping("/showFormForUpdate")
public String showFormForUpdate(@RequestParam("employeeId") int theId, Model theModel) {
Employee theEmployee = employeeService.findById(theId);
theModel.addAttribute("employee", theEmployee);
return "employees/employee-form";         

@GetMapping("/delete")
public String delete(@RequestParam("employeeId") int theId) {
employeeService.deleteById(theId);
return "redirect:/employees/list";
```

P.S. This question is general and does not refer to any code. I just want to understand, why developers use redirect instead of returning page directly.

Comment: can you please post valid code?

Comment: @Berto99 What code would you need in order to answer the question? "_why developers use redirect instead of returning page directly_"

Comment: @takendarkk because if you post code that doesn't even barely remotely compile, what's the send of posting it?

Comment: I am not the OP. I think the code was posted to show a rough example, not to compile and run. And it could be removed - it is not needed for the actual question. That's why I was curious why you needed correct code when the code seems to not be needed.

Comment: @Berto99 Sorry, didn't mean to confuse you, shouldn't have posted the code part.

Comment: aaadn because, for example, one big reason is that user, if not redirected from a POST request, if wants to reload the page, will resubmit the entire post request

Comment: in addition to this, is that if you have already a method that "knows" hot to return the homepage, why other method should "know how to build the homepage"? just redirect the user to the homepage no?